# Custom template for archive of a custom taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy, archives, archive-template

I've made a custom taxonomy named *activities*, containing items named *local*, *member*, and *national*:

```
<?php
function add_custom_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy('Activities', 'post', array(
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => array(
            // labels goes here
        ),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'activities',
            'with_front' => true, 
            'hierarchical' => true
        ),
    ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_taxonomies, 0 );
```

And I've created each taxonomy item a page, which are `taxonomy-activities-local.php`, `taxonomy-activities-member.php`, and `taxonomy-activities-national.php`.

Accessing `mydomain.com/activities/local/` is just fine. But accessing `mydomain.com/activities/` itself redirects to a 404 page. I understand fully that this normally shouldn't work. It is just like accessing `mydomain.com/tag/`, which also redirects to a 404 page.

Is there a way to use a template PHP file that I made? Hence, accessing `mydomain.com/activities/` uses that PHP file instead of the 404 page without using any plugins?

Comment: Create a page with slug `activities`?

Comment: You will need to read the https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/ taxonomy template article on WordPress.org for that information. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to reset the permalink?
I got that issue before and I just change the permalink to Plain and change back to Post name and it's no longer 404.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do it is to create a custom template page and get the list of terms (or whatever you need) on that template.

*template-activities-taxonomy.php*

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Activities Taxonomy */

get_header(); ?>

<?
$terms = get_terms( 'activities' );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ): ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>    
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And then just create a Page with the url you want (/activities) that uses that template.